# How is peanut butter flavor added to beer?

Tags: recipe-formulation, adjunct

I've encountered several commercial beers with peanut butter flavor and I'm interested in making something similar but I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.  I've seen reference to peanut butter powder but I'm not sure if this is the recommended way to do it or, even if it is, if there are other methods worth considering.

How to commercial and home brewers generally add peanut butter flavor to beer and what other prominent options exist?  Is there a straightforward way to process peanuts at home to add them to beer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PB2 peanut powder is what a local brewery was using to make there peanut butter stout. It makes sense to use powdered VS regular, regular has a lot of fats and oils in it, that would be bad for carbonation and head retention.

Answer (score 0):

Most will treat the dehydrated peanut butter just like any other spice, nut, fruit addition. 
Either  Late boil, on chill, or late fermentation. Or combo.